# how to redirect to anchor tag in view page after CodeIgniter validation

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

This is my view page.here I put anchor tag for Event
**view**

```
<a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Events</a>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
    <h3 class="box-title">Events</h3>
    <form role="form" id="EventForm"  action="<?echo base_url()?>home/submit_event" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Event Name</label>
            <input id="event_name" name="e_name" type="text" style="margin-right:20px;width:174px;height:21px;margin-left:46px ;"  class="form-control event_form">
            <?php echo form_error('e_name'); ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

Here the insertion after validation.if the validation run is false I need to redirect the anchor tag.but I don't know how this possible.Here I am doing redirect to index that's my home page

```
function submit_event()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:#B94A48">', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('e_name', 'Event Name', 'required');
    if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE )
    {
        $this->index();
        //redirect(base_url().'');

    }
    else
    {
        $event_name=$this->input->post('e_name');
        $event_data=array(
            'event_name'=>$event_name,
        );
        $this->home_model->insert_event($event_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you need to do?? clear bit

Comment: still am doing validation in event section..if the validation is false i can exists on the same event section

Comment: so use `header` funtion

Comment: you need after this `$this->index();` to load your old view??

Comment: how can i use header function?

Comment: old view means that view from anchor tag..how this load in the controller?

Comment: First of all your form tag is not closed. To redirect you can use `redirect(base_url().'home/index');`

Comment: what do you mean by anchor tags?? i dont see any anchors being set anywhere

Comment: first line of view page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to an anchor in CI you should use redirect function like this :

```
redirect('/controller/function#anchor', 'refresh');
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE )
    {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');//your controller name

    }
```

[Header Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

or

```
if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE )
    {
         redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');//your controller name

    }
```

[Redirect](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter redirection can be achieved using the redirect method in the url helper. You can use this like this

> redirect('/your controller/method', 'refresh');

Where 'your controller' is the controller that houses the method for the view page for new event add. And the 'method' is the method name inside the controller that loads the view. For reference go to this link 
[codeigniter url helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. First load the `URL helper`, then call the `redirect()` method

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url().'controller/method', 'refresh');
```

Refer [CodeIgniter Docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)